# Does Cardinality happen one at a time or it is about the whole life of the data?

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, cardinality

A   laboratory  has several chemists    who work    on  one or  more    projects.       While   working on
these   projects    a   chemist may use different   laboratory  equipment.
The laboratory  needs   to  know    the following   information about   its chemists,   projects    and 
equipment.
A   chemist has an  employee    ID, name    (first  and last)   ,   date    of  birth,  age and several phone
numbers.        A   project has a   unique  project ID  (identifier)    ,   name,   and a   project     start,  and 
finish  date.   Equipment   information     which   includes        a   serial  number  (unique)    ,   name,    and
cost    .       The laboratory  wishes  to  record  the date    when    a   given   piece   of  equipment   is  assigned
to  and returned    by  a   particular  chemist.        The laboratory  also    wishes  to  record  the hours a 
chemist works   on  a   project.
The laboratory  also    has the following business  rules.      A   chemist must    be  assigned    to  at  least
one project and one equipment   item.   A   given   piece   of  equipment   need    not be  assigned,   and 
a   given   project need    not be  assigned    either  to  a   chemist.

So, EQUIPMENT to ASSIGNEMENT, if it’s one at a time, a EQUIPMENT can only be assigned to one PROJECT at once N:1,

Or if it’s whole life, a EQUIPMENT can be ASSIGNED to one PROJECT or more in different moments M:N. 
Picture of the Diagram >> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPg0C.png)

Comment: Please use [text, not images/links, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). An image might be nice as an additional alternate or it might add additional information. Although here the image has a pile of irrelevant stuff and the relevant stuff says nothing more than the text you should give. (Although you could give the relevant sub-image as additional alternate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cardinality constraint, like every constraint, is about base tables, which are table-valued variables, and is true (and enforced) in *every* database state, ie it is also "about the whole life of the data".